# Simple toggle button that performs calculations

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to create a toggle button that will convert Inches to CM and than CM to Inches. The button with start by saying Convert to CM, and once clicked it would convert the current value from Inches to CM, afterwards the button will say Convert to Inches, and once clicked convert CM to Inches:

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong below, but it seems to be dividing first when it's suppose to multiply first, and the button doesn't change the text the first time:

```js
var flag=false;
$("#ConvertInchCm").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var val = $('#value').text()
    if(flag && ($(this).text() == "Convert to CM"))
    {
         $("#value").text(val*2.54);
         $(this).text("Convert to Inches"); 
    }
    else
    {
        $("#value").text(val/2.54);
        $(this).text("Convert to CM");
    }
       flag=!flag;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="ConvertInchCm">Convert to CM</button>
<div id="value">1</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the flag, the text should be enough to let you know what state you are in. You can also use `this.innerHTML` instead of `$(this).text()` to avoid the creation of 2 jQuery objects.

```js
$("#ConvertInchCm").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var val = $('#value').text()
    if(($(this).text() == "Convert to CM"))
    {
         $("#value").text(val*2.54);
         $(this).text("Convert to Inches"); 
    }
    else
    {
        $("#value").text(val/2.54);
        $(this).text("Convert to CM");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="ConvertInchCm">Convert to CM</button>
<div id="value">1</div>
```